# Get link from webview plugin swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am loading a URL in a webview in swift. I am trying to look for the URL from the redirect. However the webview delegate methods don't return any URLs, instead the webview opens a playerview and prints "Optional("Plug-in handled load")" . The file at the end of the URL gets opened. How could I avoid the plugin and get the end URL from the redirect instead. Thanks in advance.

The urls look like this http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=//www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVD9j36Ke94

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: @Asdrubal Thank you for your reply. What is it that you are referring to in that link?